# Find out on which programmatically generated object the contextmenu was called

Tags: c#, winforms, contextmenu

In my program, I generate Labels dynamically by right click -> new in the form:

```
private Point MouseDownLocation;
private List<Label> labelList=new List<Label>();

private void mainContextMenu_Opening(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
  MouseDownLocation = PointToClient(MousePosition);
}

private void valueToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Label label = new Label();
  label.Location = MouseDownLocation;
  label.AutoSize = true;
  label.ContextMenuStrip = valueContextMenu;
  label.Text = "test";
  this.Controls.Add(label);
  labelList.Add(label);
}
```

Next I have the valueContextMenu with the Button Delete with which I want to be able to rightclick such a generated label and then delete.

```
private void deleteToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
```

the problem is, that in this function(which is being called), there is no way of retrieving the label the menu was called on, since sender is the contextmenu..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try examining the SourceControl property of the ContextMenuStrip:

```
private void deleteToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  Control c = ((ContextMenuStrip)((ToolStripMenuItem)sender).Owner).SourceControl;
  if (c != null) {
    // do something...
  }
}
```